# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError during dynamic template management in Angular

Tags: angular, view

I need to dynamically manage templates. I want to show or hide some view based on the parameter which is changed after WebSocket message or user interacition. I use ngIf for this, but sometimes (especialy, when I reload the view, and messages comes quickly) console receive me an error

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.
```

I user Angular 8

***Main Component***

```
export class MainComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

 public view_config;

 constructor(public pluginInfoService: PluginInfoService){}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.pluginInfoService.getViewConfig().subscribe(view_config => {
     this.view_config = view_config;
   });
 }

}
```

***Main Component Template***

```
<popup-window *ngIf="view_config.show_popup_window" class="overflow_hidden h-100 w-100" [view_config]="view_config">
  <select-media *ngIf="view_config.popup_window_mode == 'select_media'" [view_config]="view_config" class="container-fluid h-100"></select-media>
  <get-contact-name *ngIf="view_config.popup_window_mode == 'get_contact_name'" [view_config]="view_config" class="container-fluid h-100"></get-contact-name>
  <chat-view *ngIf="view_config.popup_window_mode == 'chat_view'" class="container-fluid h-100 flex-column d-flex p-0"></chat-view>
  <change-media-invitation *ngIf="view_config.popup_window_mode == 'media_change_invite'" [view_config]="view_config" class="container-fluid h-100"></change-media-invitation>
</popup-window>
```

***Plugin Info Servie***

```
export class PluginInfoService {

  private view_config = {
    show_main_button: true,
    show_popup_window: true,
    popup_window_mode: 'select_media',
    show_popup_media_window: false,
    popup_media_window_mode: null,
    minimize_popup_window: false
  };

  private viewConfigStream = new BehaviorSubject(this.view_config);

  constructor() {
  }

  setViewConfigParam(param, value) {
    this.view_config[param] = value;
    this.viewConfigStream.next(this.view_config);
  }

  getViewConfig(): Observable<any> {
    return this.viewConfigStream.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The mechanism already works, but I suppose it makes more problems around it. Firstly I don't want have this errors, secondly I want to be sure that all is implemented properly. How to fix this problem ? Is this method is good ?

Comment: This is a dev environnement error, you wont get that in production.  You get this error when values are changed between the start and the end of a change detection.

Comment: So, do You think this code is quite good to manage views ?

Comment: Why are you subscribing to something static, is it going to be fetched from your backend later?

Comment: @ukn no, I only change it by service method when websocket msg comes or after user interaction. Should I return static data instead ?

Comment: ok, I think what your are doing make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid possible changes to the views whilst the [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) is still in the process of generating the page you could simply hook into a later point, e.g.

replace

```
ngOnInit()
```

with

```
ngAfterViewInit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing in `ngAfterViewInit()` didn't work for me. But

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$observable = this.myService.getObservabel()
  }, 0);
}
```

solved it for me!
Like this the subscription is made asyncron and the call gets enqued at the end of the microtask queue.